# Rails 5 error displaying twice on the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just finished adding bootstrap styles to rails 5 layouts in the views. There is an issue with an error being rendered twice. As shown in the following image.[image]

In the passangers controller, the logic for displaying the message "you already have a ride" is alocated, however I don't understand why is being render twice if the layout page display errors message in a bootstrap alert tag.

passangers_controller:

```
def create
    @passenger = Passenger.new(passenger_params)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @transportation = Transportation.find(params[:transportation_id])
    @driver = User.find(@transportation.transporter_id)
    @protest = Protest.find(@transportation.destination_id)
    @transportations = Transportation.where(destination_id: @protest.id)
    has_ride = false

    @transportations.each do |transportation|
      passenger = Passenger.find_by user_id: current_user.id
      unless (passenger.nil?)
        has_ride = true
      end
    end

    if has_ride
      redirect_to protests_path, notice: "You already have a ride."
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @passenger.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_protest_transportation_passenger_path(id: @passenger.id), notice: 'Passenger was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is views/protests/index.html.erb

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
  <% end %>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h1>Protests</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="card-block", align="center">
      <% @protests.each do |protest| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h4 class="card-title"><%= protest.name %></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p class="card-img"><a href="/protests/<%=protest.id%>"><%= image_tag protest.image.url(:thumb), class: "img-thumbnail" %></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is inside your index erb file?

Comment: @babar I just added it to the post

Comment: Could you post your protests index html erb file ? Or the one that gets rendered in protests_path

Comment: @moyom I just add it, I think I see where the error is. The flash in the index.html.erb

Comment: You have to check all the rendered templates, including layouts and partials, and see what you're actually rendering. You have it twice somewhere.

Comment: Yep, that's the error @StevenAguilar :)

Comment: @StevenAguilar so you solved this?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yes I did that was the issue.